# Discord.JS Add a button to a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to add another button to an existing message (send by the bot)
I tried:

```js
// const... log in... ....
let msg = await interaction.channel.fetchMessage(interaction.options.get('message-id'))
if(!msg || msg?.author?.id !== client.user.id) return interaction.reply({ content: "Error..." })

msg.edit({ embeds: ["a defined embed"], components: [row] })
```

When I edit the components, it replaces the first one with the new one.

How can I add a new button to the message?

Comment: Sorry I think I don't ask the good question : How to add a button without deleting the previous button

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit the whole message. Just do `message.edit({components: [row]})`

It should just add the button without editing the message

Comment: So basically you are just editing the components section of the message